# Java - paintComponent with nested loops

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, paintcomponent

I am currently trying to paint a grid with rectangles, but having some issues.

I am using an enum class for different type of `SquareTypes`:

```
public enum SquareType
{
    EMPTY, OUTSIDE, I, O, T, S, Z, J, L
}
```

These `SquareTypes` are saved in arrays containing arrays in a `Board` class. Then, `paintComponent` -- which is supposed to draw my grid -- reaches in and get these object by using:

```
public SquareType getCell(int width, int height) {
    return squares[width][height];
```

However, now when we get to `paintComponent`:

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

       EnumMap<SquareType, Color> dictionary = new EnumMap<SquareType, Color>(SquareType.class);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.EMPTY, Color.BLACK);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.I, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.J, Color.ORANGE);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.L, Color.BLUE);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.O, Color.YELLOW);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.OUTSIDE, Color.BLUE);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.S, Color.GREEN);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.T, Color.CYAN);
       dictionary.put(SquareType.Z, Color.RED);

       for (int i = 0; i < game.getHeight(); i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < game.getWidth(); j++) {
               g2d.setColor(dictionary.get(game.getCell(j,i)));
               g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 52 * j, 52 * i);

           }
       }
   }

}
```

The issue is that `paintComponent` paints every square Blue, but if I use my `getCell()`-method and check what is inside the actual cells I can clearly see that there are different `SquareTypes`.

Might also add that the first rectangle which the the program draws is supposed to always be blue. So it seems to me as if it starts painting with blue and then sticks to it all the way? Why is that?

I am really new to the programming language and would love any help.

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example that replicates the problem, so we can test it out.

Comment: Also avoid  creating the `EnumMap` in the `paintComponent` method. Initialize it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
g2d.drawRect(0, 0, 52 * j, 52 * i);
```

is clearly wrong. The method is described as follows:

```
drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

So your line draws a rectangle above all prior drawn rectangles. Thats why your final result is a big blue rectangle.

I think it should be something like this:

```
g2d.drawRect(j * 52, i * 52, 52, 52);
```